# proper onclick format

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the proper way of doing this?

```
$chatterhtml .= '<span style="float:right;" >
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="deletecmnt(this, "'.$val['id'].'", "'.BASE_URL.'");" title="Delete Chatter">x</a>
                </span>';
```

I am receiving an error in Firefox `SyntaxError: syntax error deletecmnt(this,` but this worked up until I changed from a input text to text area.

Comment: What is the rendered code? and I see here only anchor, no input nor textarea.

Comment: try $val["id"] like it. change the single quote to double in this variable only.

Comment: Well, _the proper way_ I'd say is AJAX, and using an event listener instead of `onclick`.

Comment: @elclanrs why does this work with a input box but not textarea? What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using quotes to delimit your values in the javascript *AND* in your HTML. The result is something like:
`onClick="deletecmnt(this, "0", "someurl.html");"`
which is not valid. The onClick here becomes truncated to just `onClick="deletecmnt(this, "` and the rest is treated as invalid HTML attribute data

Instead, you should do something like:

```
$chatterhtml .= "<span style=\"float: right;\">" .
  "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"deletecmnt(this, '" . $val['id'] . "', '" . BASE_URL . "');\" title=\"Delete Chatter\">x</a>" .
  "</span>";
```

Comment: This does work if I revert to an input tag instead of textarea. How resolve?

Comment: I'd give you a hug if I could. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your Resultant HTML is not valid. You have double quotes within double quotes un escaped. Try this

```
$chatterhtml .= '<span style="float:right;" ><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="deletecmnt(this, \''.$val['id'].'\', \''.BASE_URL.'\');" title="Delete Chatter">x</a></span>';
```